# Creating an own hook in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, hook

I am looking to create a hook for my own extension so that one of my other extension can use the function defined in the extension.

Does anyone know how to create a new hook for creating communication between two extension?

Comment: do you have any references of where you have looked already and some examples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Go for the Singal/Slot Pattern.

You can emit a signal in your code and register a slot that listens on that signal to hook into the process.

To emit a signal, inject the SignalSlotDispatcher:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher
 * @inject
 */
protected $signalSlotDispatcher;
```

And in your code you can emit the signal like this:

```
$this->signalSlotDispatcher->dispatch(
    __CLASS__,
    'MySignalName',
    [$param1, $param2, $this]
);
```

In your 2nd extension you can register a slot that listens an that signal in your `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility
\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \Your\Class\With\The\Signal::class,
    'MySignalName',
    Your\Class\With\The\Slot::class,    
    'mySlotMethod',
    false
);
```

Then you implement `mySlotMethod` in the Slot Class and do your stuff.

---

EDIT: I wrote a more detailed tutorial on that Topic [here](https://usetypo3.com/signals-and-hooks-in-typo3.html).

Comment: where does injecting the SignalSlotDispatcher go? in the class or in ext_localconf.php

Comment: In the class where you emmit the signal. In ext_emconf you cannot inject. That is why the Dispatcher is initialized with Generalutility::makeInstance() there.

Comment: in the emitting the signal code snippet, what is MySignalName and  [$param1, $param2, $this]? where it goes after the action method or before or inside?

Comment: 'MySignalName' is just a name for your sgnal. Choose as you like. use it again when you register a slot (see last snippet). [$param1, $param2, $this] is an array with some variables. You might pass here anything you like in order to have in present in Your\Class\With\The\Slot::mySlotMethod()

Comment: Thanks! where does this code go $this->signalSlotDispatcher->dispatch(
    __CLASS__,
    'MySignalName',
    [$param1, $param2, $this]
);

Comment: Wherever you need it. If the code execution reaches that line, all slots that are registered for the dispatched signal are executed. This is what you wanted in the first place. :)